# How to drill down charts using Anychart

Tags: anychart

I am trying to develop drill down feature using Anychart. I found a link to use drill down option but the documentation is very old and i cant able to find the latest documentation on chart drill down in Anychart documentation. Maps drill down is available on official Anychart documentation but i need chart drill down feature.

So far i tried the below code to generate the drill down but in the drill down event am not able to get the values for data or any other properties form the event argument.

i tried to log the e.data property where am getting undefined. Let me know how can i achieve this or can point to the documentation available in Anychart.

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/7.13.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.min.css">
<style>
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
        anychart.format.inputDateTimeFormat('MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss');
        chart = anychart.fromJson({
            chart: {
                type:'line',
                xAxes: [{
                    labels: {
                        textFormatter: formatter,
                        rotation: -40
                    }}],
                scales: [{ type: 'dateTime'
                }],
                xScale: '0',
                yScale: {
                    minimum: -1
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        seriesType: 'spline',
                        name: 'OCRTest',
                        connectMissingPoints:true,
                        tooltip: {
                            titleFormatter: tooltipFormatter,
                            textFormatter: textFormatterToolTip
                        },
                        stroke: {
                            color: '#008000',
                            thickness: 2
                        },
                        data:[
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:01:24","value":0.8270},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:11:25","value":0.9520},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:21:25","value":0.9210},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:31:25","value":0.9200},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:41:23","value":0.2960},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 12:51:25","value":0.1410},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:01:23","value":0.7800},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:11:24","value":0.4210},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:21:25","value":0.0630},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:31:25","value":0.8420},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:41:25","value":0.7640},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 01:51:24","value":0.1870},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:01:28","value":0.1870},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:11:25","value":0.8270},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:21:24","value":0.7170},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:31:24","value":0.9200},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:41:27","value":0.4680},
                            {"x":"03.09.2017 02:51:24","value":0.9360}
                        ]}],
                'xScroller': {
                    'enabled': true,
                },
                container:'container',
                'tooltip': {
                    'title': {
                        'enabled': true,
                    },
                    'displayMode': 'single',
                    'enabled': true
                }}
        }).draw();
        chart.addEventListener('pointClick', onPointClick);
        var credits = chart.credits();
        credits.enabled(false);
    });
    function tooltipFormatter(){
        return anychart.format.dateTime(this.x, 'MMM dd yyyy h:mm');
    }
    function formatter(){
        return anychart.format.dateTime(this.tickValue, 'MMM dd yyyy h:mm');
    }
    function textFormatterToolTip(){
        return this.seriesName + ': ' + this.value;
    }
    function onPointClick(e)
    {
        console.log(e.data);
    }

</script>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The addEventListener() is the deprecated method, it was used in the 6.x version. Please define the appropriate listener to handle points event:

```
    chart.listen("pointClick", function(e){
       onPointClick(e);
    });
```

I made the example based on your data to illustrate the idea:
http://jsfiddle.net/e570c09j/

Also, more information about how to create drilldown chart, please find here:
https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Interactivity#drilldown

Here you can find more information about the listeners and supported events:
https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Event_Listeners

Take a look at the following sample, it uses the 'pointSelect' listener to create interactive charts:
http://playground.anychart.com/docs/7.13.0/samples/CS_Interactivity_13-plain